# How to open the windows 10 keyboard with a batch file on tablet mode without minimizing current window?

Tags: windows-10, batch, cmd.exe

I have a .bat file with the following:

start OSK.exe

This opens up a keyboard. Now the issue is that this batch file is ran when the PC is on tablet mode. Unfortunately this causes the current window to minimize and the keyboard to take up the entire space. Anyone know how to bypass this?